# Status indicator on the status-bar based on the return value of a periodic execution of a command

Tags: indicator, ubuntu-mate, statusbar, mate-panel

I want to execute a command periodically and based on its output to have a visual  indication of its last return value (0: green, non-zero: red).

e.g. by using the command below I can check whether my vpn connection is still alive and healthy. `protected-node` is only accessible through vpn, so if vpn is unhealthy or down it will return non-zero.

```bash
nc -w5 -z vpn-only-accessible-node 80
```

So as said above, I am looking for a way to convert the return value of the command to visual indication in the statusbar or to some other always-visible area on my desktop.

I am using mate desktop.

Answer (score 1):

[MATE applets](https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-applets), a fork of [GNOME applets](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-applets), should contain an applet named "Command" that periodically runs a command and displays output in the top panel. You should be probably able to add this applet to your panel right away (if not, you probably need to install `mate-applets` package).

While not fully what you want (you will get a textual indication instead of colors), you can use it to execute a script that runs your command and outputs either "OK" or "ERROR" (or any other text that suits you) depending on the return code.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using [`notify-send`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/notify-send.1.html), you can always do something like this:

```bash
while sleep 5
  do
    nc -w5 -z vpn-only-accessible-node 80 && \
    notify-send --icon=network-wired "OK" "OK" || \
    notify-send --icon=network-error "ERR" "Error"
    done
```

... or in a command string that you can run by providing it as a command in e.g. startup applications so that it automatically runs at user desktop login ... Like this:

```bash
/bin/bash -c 'while sleep 5; do nc -w5 -z vpn-only-accessible-node 80 && notify-send --icon=network-wired "OK" "OK" || notify-send --icon=network-error "ERR" "Error"; done'
```

Either of the above will run your command every five seconds and send you a visual desktop notification that is different in appearance and in message.